# When dispose ViewModel instances inside another ViewModel

Tags: reactiveui

I have some Viewmodels wirh instances of another viewmodels, or Reactivelists with viewmodels.

What is the best moment to dispose the viewmodels?

Comment: Provide some samples might be helpful. How you use those sub view models can affect the answer.

Comment: for example a reactivelist with viewmodels, binded to datagrid, using the ViewModelViewHost. Or A ViewModel property binded to a ViewModelViewHost.